# How can I change visibility on google maps v3?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-styling

I want to change the visibility of the map ( roads and other labels ) in accordance to level of zoom.

Is there any way I can do that?

For example: `visibility=on` while I the zoom is <=8 and off while zoom is > 8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
  var zoomLevel = map.getZoom();
  if (zoomLevel <= 8) {
    turnVisOn();
  } else if (zoomLevel > 8) {
    turnVisOff();
  }
});
```

Then, in your `turnVisX` functions:

```
var styleArray = [
  {
    featureType: "road",
    stylers: [
      { visibility: "off" } // or "on"
    ]
  }
];
map.setOptions({styles: styleArray});
```